# How to Build gtk3 [static] using msys2?

Tags: make, gtk, build, msys

I am trying to build gtk+-3.22.30, because i cant find it [static link library] anywhere.
i downloaded msys2 32bit, install mingw32 (gcc 7.3.0) added it to environment variables in windows. pkg-config and make file also included.

i downloaded the gtk tar, file extracted, ran ./configure, it needed some dependence like pango, glib, atk, libiconv... etc.

after i download these dependencies? what do i do? do i need to compile them too?
do i need to add pkg-config to the make command? i have tried to compile one of these dependencies after i ran configure command on that i got this in msys2 console

im pretty new to build s/w from source, i know little about `./configure` `make all` `make install` commands and there parameters. am i missing linking some libraries, wrong compiler (32-bit)? how do i force build 32 bit from source?

```
 sea@DESKTOP-6D2EANF MINGW32 ~/libiconv-1.15
$ make
builddir="`pwd`"; cd libcharset && make all && make install-lib libdir="$builddi                           r/lib" includedir="$builddir/lib"
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sea/libiconv-1.15/libcharset'
cd lib && make all
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sea/libiconv-1.15/libcharset/lib'
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -o libcharset.la                            -rpath /home/sea/libiconv/lib -version-info 1:0:0 -no-undefined localcharset.lo                            relocatable.lo
libtool: link: gcc -o .libs/libcharset.dll.a  .libs/localcharset.o .libs/relocat                           able.o   -g -O2   `func_echo_all "" | /usr/bin/sed 's/ -lc$//'` -link -dll
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-min                           gw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -link
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:59: libcharset.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sea/libiconv-1.15/libcharset/lib'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:34: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sea/libiconv-1.15/libcharset'
make: *** [Makefile:42: lib/localcharset.h] Error 2
```